# UV Unwrapping overlapped with model

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm having an issue when I try to texture paint my model, I selected everything and used smart UV project with the following settings:

[image: UV Project settings]

But the texture is all overlapping and I can't paint at all on the model except for some parts of it of course.

[image: Overlapping texture]

How do I do a proper unwrapping of my model? Thank you

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but I suggest you take some time to really get to know how UV mapping works in blender. I've found this guide very helpful in the past, and though it is rather long (and potentially boring), it's a good thing to know up front, as knowing how something will be eventually be unwrapped may affect your modelling practices going forward. Guide is here - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/

Comment: I will take a look at it, thank you

Comment: You might already knew the question, but here's my suggestion: Mark seams. It doesn't have to be perfect, even lazy unwrapping works.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/